# Where is Report header in rdlc

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc

I do not find Report header in RDLC only Page Header shows up when I right click.

Answer (score 3):

In RDLC any control which is out the Table or the Tablix  it will not be repeated so if you put your controls before the table you will have the report header.

See the image

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 2):

Page Header is the report header.

Comment: A page header repeats on every page, a report header is something that should only be on the first page.

Answer (score 1):

you just right click on the report body and choose Insert->Page header.
To make it visible only on the first page you should right click on the report header->Properties->Visibility and than check print on the first page

Comment: Page header and Report header aren't the same thing!